# Disable Auto kern in Flash Professional CS 5.5

Tags: macos, textfield, swc, flash-cs5.5

I'm working with Flash Prof. CS 5.5 and have some problems using Textfields, when I export  my project as SWC. I have some dynamic TextFields, which disappear as soon as I change the text in my code.

Strangely I the TexField seems to be there, I enabled `selectable` for debugging and I get the text selection cursor and can copy the text in it by double clicking and using CMD+C. I can also trace out the content that I put in before.

I also made sure the needed characters are embedded, so that shouldn't be the problem.

I think this has something to do with the `auto kern` property of the TextField. I can't disable auto kern on my mac, but when I open the FLA on a Windows PC and do nothing but to disable auto kern and export the SWC, it works.

In the preferences of Flash I can only disable auto kern for vertical text, which didn't help.

Does anybody know how I can disable this for all TextFields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to change the Font?

*Many fonts have built-in kerning information. For example, A and V are often closer together than A and D. Flash provides horizontal tracking and kerning (for horizontal text) and vertical tracking and kerning (for vertical text).

For vertical text, you can disable kerning by default in Flash Preferences. If you do this and leave the kerning option selected in the Property inspector, kerning is applied to horizontal text only.

Using the Text tool, select one or more sentences, phrases, or text fields on the Stage.
In the Property inspector (Window > Properties), set the following options:
To use a font’s built-in kerning information, select Auto-Kern.*
(source Adobe Help).

Comment: Ok, this was just too obvious. But how come I can disable "auto kern" on Windows and use the same font that won't work on a mac. I also tried to import the font fiels from a windows on my mac and export the SWC using them, didn't help either.